# Using a C++ class inside Javascript without an .idl

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

It is possible to call methods on a class whose interface is not exposed through an .idl file?

Im my particular case, I'd like to use the **@mozilla.org/gfx/fontmetrics;1** class, whose interface **nsIFontMetrics** doesn't have a correspondent .idl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  If there is no idl file, it isn't exposed to script through XPConnect.